# How can I create a map with GPS data from EXIF?

Tags: metadata, geotagging, gps

I've been taking photos all over the country last year and now I want to create a map with all the places I've been. Luckily all my photos **are geotagged** which makes the whole process easier.

The main problem is that I haven't found a program that puts in a map all the photos you have. Picasa has a great embedded function for this, but it only works with the photos you have selected or belong to a specific album.

**Is there software that scans all my files and creates a map accordingly?**

Comment: Any particular preferred operating system?

Comment: Uhmmm, xp? I'm using a PC platform, so any window based solution (that no requires an specific version) is ok for me.

Comment: I have a strong preference for making these questions consider all operating systems. Many programs are cross platform, and it's nice to at least know about options that may be available on other OSes. If we have separate questions for each OS, there's a lot of duplication.

Comment: @mattdm - I think that is a good rule to "open up" the question to all platforms, although as a question "asker" clearly they might only have access to certain platforms so the other ones may not help them at all. I like the idea of less duplicates.

Answer (score 13):

Photoshop Lightroom does this with the "map" tab. Here is an example of my shots mapped with it:[image]

You can download a free trial from Adobe or purchase it for $100-150USD.

Comment: Sadly this is a LR4 is only compatible with Win7 and i'm stuck here with XP :(

Comment: That isn't entirely true. It runs on Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows 8, as well as multiple different versions of OS X.  Windows XP is 11 years old so I guess they just decided to stop supporting it.

Comment: Well, I meant Win7 and up.

Comment: You should be able to upgrade to windows 8 very cheaply until the end of January.

Comment: Telling people to upgrade is a sliperry slope. Often the an application requires a new OS and a new OS requires a new computer and a new computer requires new money.... and it may not work with other legacy application that someone needs, and that requires new VM software....

Comment: On the other hand XP is a 12 years old OS, and Microsoft will not support it anymore after March 2014. With this I mean: I agree that upgrading the OS just to have a geotagged map of photos is overkill, but probably it's an upgrade that should be planned this year anyway. 

There is also the alternative of buying a Windows 8 x86 DVD and install it on virtualbox in the current system, and run Lightroom in the virtual machine.

Answer (score 9):

[Geotag](http://geotag.sourceforge.net) may work for you. It's written in Java and is compatible with a number of OS's. You can even run it from the linked site without actually installing it on your system (insofar as a Java app isn't installed when you run it...)

I would recommend that whatever package you decide on that you make backup copies of your image directories until you're satisfied that the geotagging software hasn't caused any problems with the image files...

Comment: Although it doesn't have an option to recursively scan all directories, this one is the app that does exactly what i need.

Answer (score 4):

[Gpicsync](http://code.google.com/p/gpicsync/) is an open source software that can run in Windows, Linux, or Mac OS. It includes a tool to export your geotagged pictures into a KMZ file.  You can then use this KMZ file to create a map in Google Maps (and probably other mapping applications).

Comment: Too old for MacOS. Only 10.5 supported

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/) for this. Simply upload your images to Flickr, and it will [Map](http://www.flickr.com/photos/61567730@N00/map) all those with geotag info.

If you prefer software that does this, I highly recommend [Photolinker](http://www.earlyinnovations.com/photolinker/). I use their [GPSPhotolinker](http://www.earlyinnovations.com/gpsphotolinker/) software, which takes GPS track data (from a GPS device) and matches it with photos via the time stamps, then geotags the images. Photolinker takes all your geotagged images and puts them on a map. (FYI this is Mac only software)

[image]
Photo from [Early Innovations website](http://www.earlyinnovations.com/photolinker/)

Answer (score 4):

Three options:

1. For a single photo I use [Pic2Map](http://www.pic2map.com) as an online solution

   or
2. [Photo GPS Extract](http://pge.bvsoft.be/downloads.php) as a software, which both utilize EXIF GPS information to map a photo.

   or
3. For bulk photos, Canon has a software called **Map Utility** which works with both geotagged photos and also GPS logs from the camera itself:
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

I created a project recently that does exactly this, traverse your Google Photos and outputs a map (kml file).

https://bitbucket.org/blackey02/city-log

Answer (score 2):

I've used [EveryTrail](http://www.everytrail.com/) for this before. It worked really well for me, such as on [a boat trip around a lake](http://www.everytrail.com/view_trip.php?trip_id=55317) once.

Once I had the photos tagged with a time and a place, I just uploaded them (I'm pretty sure I sent them to Flickr) and had EveryTrail go get them. Once EveryTrail got them, it decoded their geotag and was able to place them on the map. Using the time stamp it was able to order them as well. Then it made a nice interactive map giving a trail and a photo at each of the points.

Comment: Could you show us an example of the end result?

Comment: And could you elaborate on your answer, maybe describe EveryTrail a bit more?

Comment: @MrCarney: If you have "comments", just add them as comments, rather than including them in your answer itself. The goal here is to provide clean, useful content that actually answer the question posed. We have a comments section after each question and answer to help keep the questions and answers themselves clean and to the point. Thanks!

Comment: @jrista Thanks for letting me know as I'm still learning my way around the stackexchange sites. I didn't think I had enough reputation points to add comments. I forgot I don't need them to comment on my own post. (doh!)

Answer (score 2):

I have used http://www.photoplace.io. It loads your photos and it can create a kmz file for Google Earth, it was really easy.

Comment: Loads your photos from where?  Is it cross-platform?

Answer (score 2):

[Photo Location Map](https://tomoyukiaota.github.io/photo-location-map/) scans image files with GPS information in a selected folder and displays them on a map.

It works on Windows or macOS.

[A demo video](https://tomoyukiaota.github.io/photo-location-map/) is helpful to understand what the application looks like.

Disclosure: I developed [Photo Location Map](https://tomoyukiaota.github.io/photo-location-map/).

Comment: This is the best app for the job!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a application that will read all the EXIF geotag information and create a KML file from those locations.  You can open the KML file in Google Earth (or Google Maps with an account).  A point is created for each photo and labeled with the file name.  You can click the point and it opens a thumbnail of the image which then allows you to open the full resolution of the image.  As long as the KML is in the same directory as the images you can share the directory and others can open the KML and see your photos mapped.

The zip file contains the raw Python script which is cross platform assuming you have installed the dependencies and have some programming skills.
The zip file includes an executable for Windows which is a click-and-use approach and will work on XP.  There is a readme file that describes this all.  Feel free to email me with problems encountered.

[https://github.com/ShuksanGeomatics/Geotagged_Images_To_KML_OLD](https://github.com/gerry1138/Geo-Tagged-Photos-to-KML-and-CSV-)

Answer (score 1):

this app i developed would list all your photos and show the date and location of the selected ones on a map: https://github.com/kamyar11/photo-location-on-google-maps

Answer (score 0):

I would use [UrbanBird.io](http://urbanbird.io). It is more fun, you get the titles, descriptions, locations and dates taken auto populated and you can get suggestions of places to visit based on where you've been.

Comment: What makes it "more fun", and for that matter, why is "fun" important in this case? And perhaps most importantly, by the site rules, if you are affiliated with a site or product, you are welcome to talk about title in answers where it fits, but you *must* disclose that.

Answer (score 0):

Photo KML is almost awesome - [Find it here](http://www.visualtravelguide.com/Photo-kml.html)
It creates a KMZ file which contains the KML plus icons and a small copy of the photos, the KMZ can be easily redistributed, unfortunately the copy of the photos are small.

Comment: `unfortunately the copy of the photos are small` I think this would not be a problem for the asker, as he is only looking to create the map of the places where he took photos. Or at least that's what I understand from his question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Metadata++ (Windows 7+).
See: http://www.logipole.com/

Comment: Nothing at the product page indicates that it will do any mapping at all. Have you used the program, or know that it will do what the OP asks about?

Answer (score 0):

The android app [A Photo Manager](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/wiki) also supports [geographic-map](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/wiki/geographic-map)

Answer (score 0):

You could use "GeoTagged Photos to Points" in ArcGIS. The will Creates points from the x-, y-, and z-coordinates stored in geotagged photos. Optionally adds photo files to features in the output feature class as geodatabase attachments.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across a pretty good online tool (**[Geotagged photos to KMZ](https://geoprocessing.online/tool/photos-to-kmz/)**) that does exactly what you need - it creates a Google Earth project in KMZ from all uploaded geotagged photos, displaying the locations of those photos. When you click on a location, the photo is displayed. The tool is available at: https://geoprocessing.online/tool/photos-to-kmz/.
You can see an example and tool description at: https://kb.geoczech.org/knowledge-base/how-to-view-photos-on-a-map/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Tonfotos](https://tonfotos.com/) indexes all your photos (and videos too - iPhone videos also have geo tags) and shows you all your events on interactive map. When zoomed out it groups together events that are near by to avoid cluttering.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Photo Album GPS Mapping Tool, available in the Windows Store, is by far the best tool out there. It uses the Google Maps API and it allows you to add geotags if they're not there.