# Create a track from gps data

Tags: gps, lightroom-5

How can I create a track or path from a bunch of geotagged photos?
I use OS 10.9 and Lightroom 5 but could not find a plugin to do that.
I mean to create a .gpx file or another format that can be read by a program that let me get some info (length of the track, total time, length and time between selected photos based on the polygonal the image position describes.
I've tried some of suggested apps from (1 year old) [How can I create a map with GPS data from EXIF?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/32420/how-can-i-create-a-map-with-gps-data-from-exif)

LR5 only displays locations in a map

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for has anything to do with photography, instead it seems like you are just interested in something like http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/ or GPS Tracking with Google Earth: https://support.google.com/earth/answer/183681?hl=en

Comment: cmason's answer from that linked question is for a program which appears to show tracks from the screenshot.  Are you looking only for a LR5 plugin?

Comment: @dpollitt This question is about photo metadata, not sure if belongs here. Maybe it can be moved to a better subdomain. I am looking for an app (preferably a LR plugin) to create a track, route, path (my Garmin calls them tracks) from geotagged photos taken with a camera that records iptc-exif metadata on each photo. A .gpx .kmz .kml for example. A file easily converted from one format to another in gpsvisualizer.com  The support.google thread talks about manually creating tracks or importing tracks

Comment: @MikeW LR shows tracks also, I need to export or at least to get some extra info (I added a sample of what kind of info)

Comment: Photolinker does export a .txt file with needed data.  Then it is possible to convert it xml in gpsvisualizer.com

Comment: gpsvisualizer.com displays the track in a map and allows you to save the track via www.everytrail.com This a nice service that also displays some statistics I mentioned in my question

Comment: I think you could have a look to http://www.photoplace.io, it seems that is only for windows and linux, but maybe it is useful for you.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to generate a GPS track from a bunch of geotagged photos. ExifTool is a command line program, available free for Windows, Mac OS or Linux.

See this page for instructions on [Inverse Geotagging](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/geotag.html#Inverse). That explains how to generate a track in GPX or KML format.

Comment: I use and love ExifTool. It is very useful managing and creating images. I also use it in a web server. Despite I found an online solution I'll try Inverse Geotagging I didn't know. Sometimes it is good to know a local solution w/o internet dependency

Comment: The gpx file created cannot be read neither by BaseCamp nor EveryTrail.com so I "converted" that gpx to a new one in gpsvisualizer.com and opened y EveryTrail.com. The difference here against using the app PhotoLinker is that in EveryTrial.com total track time is calculated and displayed, and the track is a continous line, not interrumpted because of ungeotagged photos

Answer (score 1):

The instruction that comes from the photo club I'm a member of is - synchronize the time between the camera and mobile phone, then start myTracks (android app). That will log the position at a given interval and from that yield a track file (.gpx), which can be used to mark the gps coordinates on the photos.

Comment: I use myTracks in my iPhone but I think this is a hard work in the age of google glasses. It remembers me old times when there was no way to get gps data on a DSLR metadata directly and I synchronized the time of the DSLR and my Garmin in aerial photography and geotagged later my photos