# Is there any application for PC/Desktop like for mobile phones, that allows sorting by map/cities/time?

Tags: software

See the ios app [trevi](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/trevi/id482453112?mt=8). It has a nice timeline view, maps view and places view. Does windows have any app that can do something like that? Picasa only has a timeline view, it doesn't place all photos on a map and let you browse them.

There are tons of apps like this for mobile platforms, but none I know of for the desktop?

Basically I want a desktop app, that shows

- A timeline view of photos
- A Map view of photos
- A Cities/Places view of photos
- A People's view of photos

The objective is to make it quick and easy to browse your collection according to multiple methods.

Comment: [Here's](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/32420/9161) a relevant question. I'm not a Picasa user myself, but searching around I [found](https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/43896?hl=en) that you should be able to display your photos on a map. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, that shows for the map view, but what about timeline/cities ...etc?

Comment: Well, again, I'm not a Picasa user but I assumed that the timeline view is already present in Picasa as you said `Picasa only has a timeline view`. Can you maybe reword your question such that it becomes clear what you want?

Comment: Ok I've updated the question to state it more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Lightroom basically does this and more. The only thing would be a stretch to accomplish would be browse by city, but unless you really are moving around all the time, simply tagging images with a keyword on import is easy and should likely be done anyways.

I've provided a similar example in this related question: [How can I create a map with GPS data from EXIF?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/32422/4892)

[image]